# Wordpress Adding numbers in urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I have a problem in wordpress urls. I have the url below

> http://www.example.com/sample-post/

but in search engine

> http://www.example.com/sample-post/
>
> http://www.example.com/sample-post/500012
>
> http://www.example.com/sample-post/323392
>
> http://www.example.com/sample-post/5

Please give me an idea to tackle this problem.

Comment: because your used the same slug ? or check url template form settings

Comment: I didn't understand your point I have /%postname%/ in permalinks

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found on

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70992/appending-numbers-to-url-do-not-break-the-link

> http://toscho.de/2010/wordpress-plugin-canonical-permalink/
>   Description: Removes illegal numeric suffixes from the request URI.
>   Version: 0.3 Author: Thomas Scholz Author URI: http://toscho.de
>   Created: 04.04.2010
>   */
>
> add_action('wp', 't5_canonical_request'); /**  * WordPress allows URIs
>   with any numeric suffix, e.g.:  * /canonical-page-or-postname/12345/ 
>   * This functions performs a simple check and redirects  * to the canonical URI if neccessary.  *  * @return void  */ function
>   t5_canonical_request() {
>       global $page, $post;
>
> ```
> // post, page, attachment, preview
> if ( ! is_singular() or is_preview() )
> {
>     return;
> }
>
> $permalink = get_permalink();
>
> // We don't have access to the number of sub pages here.
> // So we have to hack.
> $max_pages = substr_count(
>     $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->') + 1;
>
> if ( 1 < $page and $page <= $max_pages )
> {
>     /*
>      * Handle different permalink settings, eg:
>      * /%year%/%postname%.html or
>      * /%year%/%postname%/
>      */
>     $rev_perma_struct = strrev(get_option('permalink_structure'));
>
>     if ( '/' != $rev_perma_struct[0] )
>     {
>         $permalink .= "/$page";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         $permalink .= "$page/";
>     }
> }
>
> $host_uri       = 'http'
>                 . ( empty ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? '' : 's' )
>                 . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
> $canonical_path = str_replace($host_uri, '', $permalink);
>
> if ( ! empty ( $_GET ) )
> {
>     global $wp;
>     // Array
>     $allowed = $wp->public_query_vars;
>
>     $out_arr = array();
>
>     foreach ( $_GET as $k => $v )
>     {
>         if ( in_array($k, $allowed ) )
>         {
>             $out_arr[] = $k . ( empty ( $v ) ? '' : "=$v" );
>         }
>     }
>
>     if ( ! empty ( $out_arr ) )
>     {
>         $canonical_path .= '?' . implode('&', $out_arr);
>     }
> }
>
> if ( $canonical_path == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )
> {
>     return;
> }
> // Debug current result:
> #print '<pre>' . var_export($canonical_path, TRUE) . '</pre>';
>
> // Change it or return 'false' to stop the redirect.
> $canonical_path = apply_filters(
>     't5_canonical_path',
>     $canonical_path
> );
>
> if ( FALSE != $canonical_path )
> {
>     header('Location: ' . $permalink, true, 301);
>     die("<a href='$permalink'>$permalink</a>");
> }
>
> return; }
> ```